# TensorFlow toco - convert from *.pb to *.tflite error

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-lite

When try to convert *.pb model to *.tflite (for running on android) using toco converter of TensorFlow, I got the following

```
2018-05-11 20:38:10.841641: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:242] Loading SavedModel with tags: { serve }; from: /home/user_name/Downloads/model_directory
2018-05-11 20:38:10.847390: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:291] SavedModel load for tags { serve }; Status: fail. Took 6042 microseconds.
2018-05-11 20:38:10.848098: F tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/toco_saved_model.cc:50] **Non-OK-status:** tensorflow::LoadSavedModel(tensorflow::SessionOptions(), tensorflow::RunOptions(), model_path, tags, bundle) **status: Not found:** Could not find meta graph def matching supplied tags: { serve }. To inspect available tag-sets in the SavedModel, please use the SavedModel CLI: `saved_model_cli`Failed to load exported model from /home/user_name/Downloads/model_directory. **Ensure the model contains the required tags 'serve'.**
```

**Any idea how to solve it?**

Machine details:
OS Platform and Distribution - ubuntu x64, 
python version is 3.5.2, 
TensorFlow installed from - pip, 
TensorFlow version - cpu version 1.8.0, 
Bazel version - 0.13.0, 
CUDA/cuDNN version - no cuda, 
GPU model and memory - no gpu, 
Exact command to reproduce - no need

Comment: I solved it. thanks!

Comment: Please post your solution and mark your question as solved @THBP. You are helpling others.